Missing authorization rules account
Not able to use ruleSet with updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2 where we are setting ruleSet and than updating authority in metadata.
  const tx = await createProgrammableNft(umi, {
    mint,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROYALITY),
    name: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PNFT_NAME,
    symbol: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SYMBOL,
    image: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_URL,
    primarySaleHappened: true,
    uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URI,
    collection: {
      key: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COLLECTION_ADDRESS),
      verified: false,
    },
    creators: [
      {
        address: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER),
        share: 100,
        verified: false,
      },
    ],
    ruleSet: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RULE_SET_ADDRESS),
  })
    .add(
      transferSol(umi, {
        destination: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER),
        amount: sol(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NFT_PRICE),
        source: wallet?.publicKey,
      })
    )
    .add(
      updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2(umi, {
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER), // New authority
      })
    )
    .sendAndConfirm(umi);


updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2 method doesn't contain an updateAuthority field.
The correct field you are looking for is newUpdateAuthority
// -- snip
updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2(umi, {
            mint: mint.publicKey,
            newUpdateAuthority: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER), // New authority
        })
// -- snip


Okay I have updated 'updateAuthority' with 'newUpdateAuthority' but still getting error '  "Program log: Missing authorization rules account"
'

I think you will need to set the ruleSet account in your update ix as well ruleSet: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RULE_SET_ADDRESS),

No its not working i have added ruleSet inside 'updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2' but its giving same error.
